# How to store SensorThings query result into a variable in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sensorthings

I am trying to read a thing entity from a **SensorThings** server (https://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/) by using **GET** method via **JavaScript/jQuery** and store the result into a variable named **thing** so that I can use the variable in another part of the script.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Read Thing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Read Thing</h1>
    <h2 id="thing_name"></h2>
    <script>
        var thing = $.ajax({
            url: "https://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function(response, status){
                console.log(response);
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And after I run it in the browser, I got the result like this:

```
{@iot.id: 1785996, @iot.selfLink: "http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)", description: "Thing Description 15", name: "Thing Name 16", properties: {…}, …}
@iot.id
:
1785996
@iot.selfLink
:
"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)"
Datastreams@iot.navigationLink
:
"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)/Datastreams"
HistoricalLocations@iot.navigationLink
:
"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)/HistoricalLocations"
Locations@iot.navigationLink
:
"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)/Locations"
description
:
"Thing Description 15"
name
:
"Thing Name 16"
properties
:
{Thing Property Name 16: "Thing Property Description 16", Thing Property Name 15: "Thing Property Description 15"}
__proto__
:
Object
```

Based on that result, I tried to do some query:

```
>>> thing
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}abort: ƒ (a)always: ƒ ()complete: ƒ ()done: ƒ ()error: ƒ ()fail: ƒ ()getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)pipe: ƒ ()progress: ƒ ()promise: ƒ (a)readyState: 4responseJSON: {@iot.id: 1785996, @iot.selfLink: "http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)", description: "Thing Description 15", name: "Thing Name 16", properties: {…}, …}responseText: "{"@iot.id":1785996,"@iot.selfLink":"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)","description":"Thing Description 15","name":"Thing Name 16","properties":{"Thing Property Name 16":"Thing Property Description 16","Thing Property Name 15":"Thing Property Description 15"},"Datastreams@iot.navigationLink":"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)/Datastreams","HistoricalLocations@iot.navigationLink":"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)/HistoricalLocations","Locations@iot.navigationLink":"http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)/Locations"}"setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)state: ƒ ()status: 200statusCode: ƒ (a)statusText: "OK"success: ƒ ()then: ƒ ()__proto__: Object
>>> thing.responseJSON
{@iot.id: 1785996, @iot.selfLink: "http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)", description: "Thing Description 15", name: "Thing Name 16", properties: {…}, …}
>>> thing.responseJSON["name"]
"Thing Name 16"
>>> var thing_name = thing.responseJSON["name"]
undefined
>>> thing_name
"Thing Name 16"
```

It seemed that the code run successfully. However, when I insert the query into the script and tried to display the output in the console (I only display the script tag here, other lines are the same as the code above), such as:

```
<script>        
        var thing = $.ajax({
            url: "https://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function(response, status){
                console.log(response);
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
        var thing_name = thing.responseJSON["name"];
        console.log("Thing Name: " + thing_name);
        // I want to insert the variable into a h2 tag in the page
        document.querySelector("#thing_name").innerHTML = thing_name;
    </script>
```

I got an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined
    at read_thing.htm:36
(anonymous) @ read_thing.htm:36
read_thing.htm:27 {@iot.id: 1785996, @iot.selfLink: "http://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)", description: "Thing Description 15", name: "Thing Name 16", properties: {…}, …}
```

It seemed that the script did not store the result into the variable **thing** successfully. When I tried to display the content of the variable in the console, the output was **undefined**.

So, how should I modify my script to get the result into a variable? Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that code near the end of your scripts into the `success` method of the ajax call, like this:

```
<script>
    var thing = $.ajax({
        url: "https://scratchpad.sensorup.com/OGCSensorThings/v1.0/Things(1785996)",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var thing_name = thing.responseJSON["name"];
            console.log("Thing Name: " + thing_name);
            // I want to insert the variable into a h2 tag in the page
            document.querySelector("#thing_name").innerHTML = thing_name;
            return data;
        },
        error: function(response, status){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to put the name and description using thing.responseJSON["name"] and thing.responseJSON["description"]. Both of them can be run successfully. However, when I tried to use thing.responseJSON["properties"], why the output was [object Object], not the JSON Objectt inside it?  How to get the data inside that object?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: To be able to see an object as a string, you need to format the object as a string in some way. One quick and easy way to do that is `JSON.stringify(obj)`. If you're going to try to display that in your document it would be better to use the `textContent` property of a DOM element instead of `innerHTML`.